# Scheme - infinte loop and memory

Tags: scheme

I have the function:

```
((lambda (x) (x x))
 (lambda (x) (x x)))
```

and it produces an infinite loop. My question is about the memory map. We know that the stack would overflow, because I open a new frame each call. But what will be on the heap? As I understood it, on every call a new closure would be created on the heap, but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack will not overflow, because Scheme mandates [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (or something equivalent to it). No new call frames are created. Also, only constant heap allocation is required to execute this function; the interpreter needs only evaluate two `lambda` expressions, producing two closures.

If you want to fill up memory, do something like

```
(let loop ((l 0))
  (loop (cons l l)))
```

Comment: So why I come to inifinte loop?

Comment: No, Scheme does not mandate TCO. It does mandate proper tail calls (PTC), i.e., unbounded tail calls cannot consume unbounded memory. TCO is one way to implement PTC, but there are other approaches, such as "Cheney on the MTA".

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: never heard of that. Amended the answer.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: Only 'proper tail recursion'

Comment: @leppie: You mean tail calls in general are not required to be proper? :-O

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: From what I understand, calling say `(car 'foo)` in a tail context need not be a tail call as it can be proven not to be recursive. Anyways, that's how I 'cheat' a little extra performance in IronScheme  :)

Comment: @leppie: Well, in that case, you're not dealing with unbounded tail calls anyway, so that satisfies the Scheme requirement. :-)

Comment: @leppie: putting a call such as (car 'foo) in tail position is by definition a tail call. Check out the definition of tail call.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I've never seen anyone use the term TCO to refer to a specific implementation strategy for proper tail calling.  I'm delighted to see the term PTC gain ascendance over the problematic TCO, but I don't believe that TCO means what you think it means.

Comment: @JohnClements: Inconceivable! :-P So maybe I'm mistaken, but I always thought of TCO as translating tail calls to a jump, whereas other PTC approaches include using the heap for call frames and letting dead ones get collected.

Comment: I definitely agree that there are multiple implementation strategies for PTC.  This is really just a question of how people choose to use their terms. Honestly, your definitions make perfect sense; I just don't think they're the standard ones.